# jQuery effect causes element to reposition during animation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

When I do an animated show/hide on the `select` element it repositions itself during the animation. I can't do anything about the style of the "body"; it's the standard class markup in the app. Is there some simple CSS I can apply to the `select` element prevent it from repositioning?

**Update:** Added the third `select` element to the code and example

example: http://jsfiddle.net/DSULq/8/

```
<div id="body" style="position: absolute; top: 100px;">
    <div id="toolbar" style="background-color: grey; width: 400px;">
        <select>
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
            <option>D</option>
            <option>E</option>
        </select>
        <select id="toggleMe">
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
            <option>D</option>
            <option>E</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
            <option>D</option>
            <option>E</option>
        </select>
    </div>
<div>
<button>do effect</button>

$("button").click(function () {
    if ($("#toggleMe").is(":visible")) {
        $("#toggleMe").hide("slide", "slow");
    } else {
        $("#toggleMe").show("slide", "slow");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $("#toggleMe").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DSULq/3/)

Comment: `.animate({width:'toggle'},"slow");` looks pretty good. I didn't know you could pass 'toggle'!

Comment: Yes, if you look into the [animate docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), we have option for that.

Comment: Thanks, I went with the code from the third fiddle, `$("#toggleMe").animate({width:'toggle'},"fast");`. Here it is with the extra `select` element: http://jsfiddle.net/DSULq/17/

Answer (score 0):

Just use a fixed position for #toggleMe:

CSS:

```
 #toggleMe {
     position: fixed;
     top: 100px;
     left: 50px;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jk46K/1/

Comment: not really what I'm looking for there since would be some extra work involved to dynamically set the top & left

Comment: Right.  You would use jquery to find pull the 'top' from the #toolbar. The 'left' would be the width of the other select (plus a few pixels).

Comment: Also, `position: fixed` is not what we want if the page happens to be scrollable: http://jsfiddle.net/jk46K/2/